# Handling different constructor arguments with generic class

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm creating a `Grid` class and want the user to be able to instantiate the class in a variety of ways.

```js
const grid = new Grid()  // an empty grid
const grid = new Grid([[0, 0], [0, 1]])  // from coordinates [x, y]
const grid = new Grid([new Tile(0, 0), new Tile(0, 1)])  // from Tile instances
const grid = new Grid([new TileWithTerrain(0, 0), new TileWithTerrain(0, 1)])  // from extended tile instances
```

Internally, the Grid class has a data structure that stores the Tiles (a Map here).

```js
class Grid<T extends Tile> {
  tiles = new Map<T>();
  setTile(tile: T) {
    this.tiles.set(tile.toString(), tile);
  }
  constructor();
  constructor(coords: Iterable<Coords>);
  constructor(tiles: Iterable<T>);
  constructor(input?: Iterable<T> | Iterable<Coords>) {
    if (!input) return;
    for (const t of input) {
      if (t instanceof Tile) {
        this.setTile(t);
      } else {
        this.setTile(new Tile(coord));  // ts(2345) error here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When setting a new Tile given an input coordinate, this understandably errors, since I'm passing a Tile when it is expecting T in the `setTile` method.

```
Argument of type 'Tile' not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

How do I achieve the desired behavior? In a nutshell, it is a grid that will accept both an iterable of coordinates to create a store of Tile objects, and an iterable of extended Tile objects to create a store of those extended Tile objects.

Rephrased the question might be:
How can I enforce T = Tile when `Iterable<Coords>` is passed to the constructor?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to provide a [mre] others can paste into their own standalone IDEs and get to work on the issue; any third-party or private types or values should be defined for us, or even better, replaced with native versions.  My IDE doesn't know what to make of `Tile`, `Coords`, etc, and I'd rather not guess about that and possibly come up with an inapplicable solution.